# Vertically center a text on a listview row

Tags: android, listview, row, center

I'm trying to make a listview with a text and an image for each row.
The image should be on the right and the text should ocupy the rest of the row. The text should be verticaly centered.
I can do all this except the centered part.
This is what I have after many failed attempts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/widget71"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:gravity="center_vertical">
<TextView
  android:id="@android:id/text1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_marginTop="6px"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
  android:text="@+id/text1"
  android:layout_weight="01"
  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_vertical|center_horizontal|center|clip_vertical"/>
<ImageView
  android:id="@android:id/icon"
  android:layout_width="30px"
  android:layout_height="40px"
  android:layout_marginTop="8px"
  android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
  android:layout_marginRight="8px"
  android:src="@drawable/delete"
  android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

No matter what the text is allways shown on top of the row.
I've already seen some reports that this may happen because of the way the xml is inflated when it's done manually. But I don't do that. I leave it to the framework.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use a `RelativeLayout` that contains a `TextView` and an `ImageView`.

For both I use the  `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` attribute. Works fine for me.

Comment: At last it worked!!
Your answer was it. Although I also used piotrpo answer (is it possible to accept both?).

Answer (score 2):

add this to textview

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

or

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 1):

User RelativeLayout instead LinearLayout Set fill_parent for TextView and wrap_content for ImageView.